# wakeonlan from remote host

Tags: server, ssh, remote-access, acpi, wakeonlan

I have setup `wake on lan` service on my server. Everything works fine on local area network:

```
root@server$: poweroff
user@local$ wakeonlan AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
```

and the server wakes up.

`AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF` is a MAC address of my `server`, which has IP `192.168.1.2` and hostname: `example.com`. It is connected to the router, which has IP 192.168.1.1 (public: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)

When the server is up, I can ping:

```
ping example.com
```

or login via ssh:

```
ssh user@example.com
```

So far, so good. Now I'm able to wake the server up from local area, but how to wake the server from the remote location?

I tried: `user@local$ wakeonlan -i xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF`, but it does not work (nothing happens;).

Do I have to configure my router somehow to forward magic packets? How?

### The solution

After [Ragnar's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19633/wakeonlan-from-remote-host/19634#19634) the solution looked very easy.

But actually, it was a bit tricky.

My router is `Linksys WAG200g`, which does not support Wake on LAN by default. Furthermore, it does not allow to forward to triplets above `254` (my broadcast address was `192.168.1.255`).

The solution was to forward UDP port `7` to the address of the server, which was `192.169.1.2`, then call:

```
wakeonlan -i example.com -p 7 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
```

Also I installed new firmware:

- [OpenWag200](http://sourceforge.net/projects/?q=wag200g)

which is a great router options upgrade (e.g. adds Wake on LAN option).

I also changed my netmask from `255.255.255.0` to `255.255.255.128`, so my broadcast is now `192.168.1.127` and passes the router validation rules.

Here is the script I use to connect to the machine, and wake it up if needed:

```
#!/bin/bash
## This sends magic packets to Wake on Lan
## please note, you must formard port 7 to the target machine on your router

## host to wake up
host="example.com"
## mac address of the machive to wake up
mac="AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF"
## user to login
user="administrator"

echo "Looking for $host..."
wget -q --tries=2 --wait=1 --waitretry=5 http://$host/
if [ $? -ne 0 ];
then
    echo "$host is not available."
    echo "Waking up $host."
    wakeonlan -p 7 -i $host $mac
    echo "$host is booting up.  Please wait..."
    sleep 30
    wget -q --waitretry=5 --wait=5 http://$host/
    echo ^G
    echo $host is up! Lucky you!
fi
ssh "$user@$host"
```

Don't forget to install: [wakeonlan](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/wakeonlan)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to forward UDP port 9 to the broadcast address in your network (192.168.1.255, or alike).

Comment: Additionally, some routers have a WOL function built into them, so if you connect to your router, you can issue the WOL that way.